# Syntax in Trigger creation Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, odbc

```
CREATE TRIGGER expiryset  ON test FOR INSERT
BEGIN 
DECLARE exp TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE name TEXT;
SET @name := (SELECT name from test ORDER BY created_at DESC limit 1);
SET @exp := (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,2,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));
UPDATE test SET expiry = @exp WHERE name= @name; 
END;
```

the above trigger works but only when executed I cannot save it. Whats wrong with the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the `DELIMITER` to something different from default `;` to treat you whole code together.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER expiryset  AFTER INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
DECLARE exp TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE name TEXT;
SET @name := (SELECT name from test ORDER BY created_at DESC limit 1);
SET @exp := (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,2,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));
UPDATE test SET expiry = @exp WHERE name= @name; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I still get an syntax error:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON test FOR INSERT
BEGIN 
DECLARE exp TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE name TEXT;
SET @name :=' at line 1
mysql> 
mysql> DELIMITER ;

Comment: You use SQL Server syntax for the trigger definition. Now it fixed, you must define trigger rising event (AFTER/BEFORE) depending of your need.